# Não estou conseguindo pegar os valores do meu arquivo HTML com o DOM do meu programa em JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Boa tarde gente, fiz um programa com HTML e JS para estudar array.repeat(), mas não estou conseguindo pegar os valores de nenhum dos input's, coloquei o contador na função para ter certeza de que este é o problema do meu código, segue o código, tanto do HTML quanto do JS:

```js
const palavra = toString(document.getElementById("palavra").value);
const quantidadeDeVezesRepetidas =
  Number(document.getElementById("quantidade").value);
let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
const botao = document.getElementById("botao");

botao.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    resultado.innerText = `${palavra.repeat(i)}`;
  }
  resultado.innerText += `\nFIM`;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="palavra" id="palavra">
<input type="number" name="quantidade" id="quantidade">

<button id="botao">Repetir</button>

<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Comment: testa com a linha `let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");` dentro da função, deve estar setando essa variável antes do `DOM` estar pronto

Comment: Já fiz isso e o resultado o mesmo, [object Undefined].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, como o colega Ricardo comentou você está pegando os valores dos inputs antes de ter valores neles, tem que pegar os valores na função que estarão atualizados, o **toString** é desnecessário nesse contexto ali, pq o valor de um input `HTML` já é **`string`**, e aí pelo que entendi a variável `quantidadeDeVezesRepetidas` seria o parâmetro para o laço de repetição:

```js
const palavra = document.getElementById("palavra");
const quantidadeDeVezesRepetidas = document.getElementById("quantidade");
let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
const botao = document.getElementById("botao");

botao.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= Number(quantidadeDeVezesRepetidas.value); i++) {
    resultado.innerText = `${palavra.value.repeat(i)}`;
  }
  resultado.innerText += `\nFIM`;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="palavra" id="palavra">
<input type="number" name="quantidade" id="quantidade">

<button id="botao">Repetir</button>

<p id="resultado"></p>
```